# pyftpdlib ftp server unavailable from outside local network

Tags: python, docker, ftp, connection-refused

my server is simple:

```
from pyftpdlib import servers, handlers
address = ("0.0.0.0", 21)
server = servers.FTPServer(address, handlers.FTPHandler)
server.banner = "Welcome to My FTP Server"
handler = server.handler
handler.authorizer.add_user("username", "password", ".", perm="elr")
handler.authorizer.add_anonymous(".", perm="elr")
handler.masquerade_address = '97.117.28.178' # from `curl ifconfig.me`
handler.passive_ports = range(60000, 60100)  
server.serve_forever()
```

running in a docker container:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 20:20 -p 21:21 -p 60000-60100:60000-60100 python:slim bash
```

then I run a client (in the same image):

```
import os
from ftplib import FTP
class FTPClient:
    def __init__(self, host):
        self.host = host
    def _connect(self):
        self.ftp = FTP(self.host)
        self.ftp.set_pasv(True)
        self.ftp.login('username', 'password')
    def _disconnect(self):
        ''' Disconnect from the FTP server '''
        self.ftp.quit()
    def connect(self):
        self.ftp = FTP(self.host)
        self.ftp.login('username', 'password')
    @staticmethod
    def manageConnection(func):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self._connect()
            result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self._disconnect()
            return result
        return wrapper
    @manageConnection
    def pull(self, filename: str, path: str = None, local: str = '.') -> bool:
        if path is not None:
            self.ftp.cwd(path)
        if filename in self.ftp.nlst():
            # Specify the desired folder or path here
            local_path = os.path.join(local, filename)
            with open(local_path, 'wb') as file:
                self.ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, file.write)
            return True
        return False
    @manageConnection
    def view(self, path: str = None) -> bool:
        if path is not None:
            self.ftp.cwd(path)
        for file in self.ftp.nlst():
            print(file)
        return False
```

and it works fine locally:

```
f = FTPClient('127.0.0.1')
f.connect() # works - I see logs on server
f.pull('utils.py') # works - downloads files
```

but when I point it to the public address it fails:

```
f = FTPClient('97.117.28.178')
f.connect() # doesn't work - no log entries on server, it doesn't even reach it

> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 13, in wrapper
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in _connect
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/ftplib.py", line 121, in __init__
    self.connect(host)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/ftplib.py", line 158, in connect
    self.sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/socket.py", line 851, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/socket.py", line 836, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

What could be the cause of this? I want the FTP server to be accessible online.

Comment: Issue is not within your code but how you setup the docker networking.. maybe adding the public ip  where you want to publish the server to - to your -p args might help.

Comment: `docker run --rm -it -p 20:20 -p 21:21 -p 60000-60100:60000-60100 python:slim bash` these ones?